# Why is the user defined time's location nil

Tags: go

I'm using go 1.13 and I have a user defined type of type `time.Time`, and when creating that value with a given location of `UTC`, the `loc` attribute is still `nil` (having a nil `loc` causes panics in certain time functions, so this is not acceptable). Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/WLWNurk7Q07).

```
type CustomTime time.Time

func main() {
    t := CustomTime(time.Date(2020, time.July, 23, 1, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC))
    fmt.Printf("%+v",t) // prints {wall:0 ext:63731062800 loc:<nil>}
}
```

FYI: background info, I'm using this custom time to implement `Scan()` for my database handler, and when I compare a custom time value defined above (with `nil` location to the value from the db (non-`nil` location), my tests are failing due to the comparison failing. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity: which database driver doesn't support time.Time directly?

Comment: @Peter, not that scanning the base `time.Time` isn't supported, rather I wanted to format the time in layoutISO8601 = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z" directly on `Scan()`.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the doc, time.Time is of type

```
type Time struct {
    //...
    wall uint64
    ext  int64
    
    // loc specifies the Location that should be used to
    // determine the minute, hour, month, day, and year
    // that correspond to this Time.
    // The nil location means UTC.
    // All UTC times are represented with loc==nil, never loc==&utcLoc.
    loc *Location
}
```

nil `loc` actually means UTC. You can verify the same by printing the equality

```
fmt.Println(time.UTC == time.Time(t).Location())

// Output: true
```

You see a nil when you print `t` because you are literally printing the struct `Time` without using its default `Stringer` as you have wrapped it with a Custom Type i.e. `CustomTime`. Hence the `loc` field will be nil.

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", time.Time(t))
// This will print UTC for the location.
```

If you want to use `CustomTime` everywhere, instead of creating a type alias you can embed `time.Time` in a struct so that `CustomTime` can behave like `time.Time`

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func main() {
    t := CustomTime{time.Date(2020, time.July, 23, 1, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)}
    fmt.Printf("%+v", t) // Prints: 2020-07-23 01:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```